# Is it possible to use environment variables while declaring jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Tags: java, web-applications, jboss

I want to have this sort of `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` :

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <resources>
           <resource-root path="{PROPERTY_FILE_LOCATION}" />
        </resources>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

By this, I want property files placed at the location defined by the **environment variable** `PROPERTY_FILE_LOCATION` to be loaded in the classpath. Is it possible to do this? I'm using **JBoss 6.4**

My entire purpose here is to get my property files placed in an external location, to be loaded into the classpath by JBoss (the files are being used in a jar that I cannot modify). I don't want to hardcode the location either.